# reduce the height of the scrollbar in html

Tags: html, css, scroll, scrollbar

```
 ::-webkit-scrollbar {
   width: 5px;
   height:7px;

  }
 /* Track */
   ::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
     background: #888; 
    }

 /* Handle */
 ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: #e51837; 
  }

  /* Handle on hover */
 ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
    background: #e51837; 
  }
```

so here I can mention the width of the scrollbar, But for height it is not working. Can somebody tell me how to change the height of the scrollbar?

Comment: use **height: auto;** property.

Comment: what is the logic behind this? the height should fit the wrapper

Comment: **height: 7px !important;**

Comment: The css works fine. Of course the height works only for a horizontal scrollbar and the width only for a vertical scrollbar, which is as expected. http://jsfiddle.net/x7jeo1ap/